# How to be redirected from "Edit Form", after clicking Save, to the "Display Form" of the already edited/modified Item?

Tags: javascript, list-view, ribbon, edit-form, display-form

How to be redirected from "Edit Form", after clicking Save button, to the "Display Form" of the already edited/modified Item?
Presently it redirects me to the entire list view and I have to search for the item to open it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var button = $("input[id$=SaveItem]");
    // change redirection behavior
    button.removeAttr("onclick");
    button.click(function() {
        var elementName = $(this).attr("name");
        var aspForm = $("form[name=aspnetForm]");
        var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.get(0).action;
        var currentSourceValue = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldPostbackUrl);
        var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue, "MyRedirectionDestination.aspx");

        if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
        WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newPostbackUrl, false, true));
    }); 
});
```

Read more [here](https://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/08/19/custom-redirect-after-creating-a-new-sharepoint-item/)

I did not test the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A twisted-thinking idea..

You could, on the AllItems page, check in the `document.referrer`, if you came from a New Form, then use JavaScript to get the recent ID and do a redirect

**If** your AllItems View is sorted with the latest entry first it can be as easy as as puttin a CEWP below the ListView or a OnPostRender CSR script:

```
if(document.referrer.search('NewForm.aspx')>0){
   document.location="DispForm.aspx?ID=" + ctx.ListData.Row[0].ID
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Sharepoint 2013 the above methods didn't work porperly. Based on this [blog post](http://spoodoo.com/change-default-form-button-redirect-simple-way/) I've been able to setup the below solution (in vanilla javascript):

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('input[id$="SaveItem"]');
var redirectTo = "https://my.website.com/site/something/Pages/Wait.aspx";
for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
  // overwrite "STSNavigate()" when clicking on the save button
  elems[i].setAttribute("onclick", "STSNavigate = function(){ window.location.href = '" + redirectTo + "' }; " + elems[i].getAttribute("onclick"))
}
```

My form is not opening into a modal. If you open it into a modal, you may have to add the below code:

```
// force PostBackRequired to true in the context, otherwise it won't work if you open it into a modal
WPQ2FormCtx.PostBackRequired=true;
```